# React component not catching some styles from styles.css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm starting to make a registration page in ReactJS, but when I apply styles in my **styles.css** file, some don't work and some do.

This is my **RegisterPage.jsx** component:

```
export default function RegisterPage() {
  return (
    <>
        <div className="row g-0">
            <div className="col-7 background">Background</div>
            <div className="col-5 registerForm">RegisterForm</div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is my **styles.css**:

```
body{
    background: #cccaaa;
}

.background{
    background: "#8d45b7";
}

.registerForm{
    background: "#fff";
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Of course I added my **styles.css** to my **index.html** file:

```
<!-- My CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" href="./src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The only style that is being applied correctly from my **styles.css** is:

```
body{
    background: #cccaaa;
}
```

But the styles that I defined through classes, don't work unless I do this in my component, for example in the **RegisterForm**:

```
export default function RegisterPage() {
  return (
    <>
        <div className="row g-0">
            <div className="col-7">Background</div>
            <div
                className="col-5"
                style={{ 
                    background: "#fff",
                    height: "100vh",
                }}>
                RegisterForm
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

And of course I would like to define my styles in my **styles.css** and not in my component, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

change it to this:

```
.background {
    background-color: #8d45b7;
}

.registerForm {
    background: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the mistake, I was writing:

```
background: "#8d45b7";
```

Instead of:

```
background: #8d45b7;
```

Silly mistake :)

Comment: Also: `background-color` would be more suitable.